# Unable to see global variable in certain C file, value seems to reset

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, global-variables

I have a very frustrating bug that others on the team can't reproduce. I have tried cleaning the project, wiping the directory, pulling from the repository, rebuilding, and even testing in VS 2013.

Background: a.c, b.c, c.c and b.inc are all compiled into a DLL (assume they are externed). `setfoo()` is called first from managed code. So far so good.

Later on, `testfoo()` is called. The global variable is fine, there are no issues. Then  `testfoo2()` is called. This is where things get interesting. I have the memory debugger on with `foo's` address, and it **will read 4 in memory**. However, if you hover over code in visual studio, it returns 0!. Also, it will output 0. There are many global variables (including `FILE` handles and they are reset to zero(causing nasty ASSERT failures), ONLY in c.c, but are fine when inspected with the debugger). There are many other x.c modules with that include that have no issues.

Ok, now `testfoo()` is called again. Everything is fine in b.c world. The scary part is that the issue happens on only on my workstation! Any clues on how to debug this?

This is from my memory, I believe the code is very close to this skeleton:

**b.inc**

```
int foo;
```

**a.c**

```
#include <b.inc>
void setfoo(){
    foo = 4;
}
```

**b.c**

```
#include <b.inc>
void testfoo(){
    printf(foo); //works
}
```

**c.c**

```
#include <b.inc>
void testfoo2(){
    printf(foo); //foo is now 0
}
```

To Add: This is very complex, legacy code (think 70s), in a very large company and not much can be changed. There are thousands of variables that would be affected if we start adding extern. Also, I tried extern on one variable, and it still has an issue with that file.

**I left out one tidbit. 'testfoo2()' launches in a managed thread.** Again, this seems to be related to my machine, could be some setting in visual studio, dunno at this point, we want to just re-image the box.

Comment: Why do you use `.inc` (just out of curiosity) when the recommended extension is `.h`

Comment: The code is horribly outdated (probably from the mid 70s) and has to stay :(. extern is not allowed.

Comment: Why are you working on a project that disallows `extern`? If I were you, I'd quit. Anyone who thinks `extern` shouldn't be allowed deserves nearly every C program written shoved in their face. As for why you can't change `.inc` to `.h`, it could be done, just may take a while.

Comment: That is another story. Nothing can be changed, because of engineering calculations and stuff. I was shot down when I made suggestions to modernize code. It is being adapted to a very slick WPF UI.

Comment: So how do you want to debug code without making changes to the code?

Comment: The feedback I'm getting is it works everywhere else, so it can't be changed. I did try extern BTW, same issue. This function is called from a C# managed thread. My concern is now some compiler setting, I was told the machine may get reimaged if it isn't solved by tomorrow, so I hope to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare as extern:

```
extern int foo;
```

And then in one (and only one) of the source files you define it:

```
int foo;
```

That way there is only one symbol in one source file, and all other sources including the header know to link to it.  If you omit `extern` then each source file thinks it has its own local, private copy of `foo`.

So which file should define it?  The one that is most relevant.  I would say `a.c`, since that provides functions to operate on `foo`.  I would consider that file to be the 'owner'.  However, it's a little confusing because you declare it in `b.inc`, suggesting that `b.c` is the owner.

Answer (score 1):

try this.

b.inc

```
extern int foo;
```

a.c

```
#include <b.inc>
int foo;

void setfoo(){
    foo = 4;
}
```

Comment: Why does this fix the OP's issue?

Comment: I'm thinking that a, b and c all have different foos

Comment: I'm concerned now this may have something to do with the function being called from a managed thread.

Comment: No, I've posted this, it may have to do with threading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918025/calling-a-dll-from-a-thread-and-global-variables-in-c

Answer (score 0):

**I posted this in another thread, but I'll duplicate the answer here. It is a pretty subtle bug that may save you a few hours:**

Ok, here is what happened: (In case you run into this in the future)

1)On a prior build someone split all the C# Extern dll calls into two files.( I wasn't told)

2)They created a post build process to copy the dll (see where this is going) to another directory.

3)There was a user settings file involved which wasn't in the repo, but had a default in code.

4)One of the extern DLL functions kept my original default (in filea.cs), but the new default (fileb.cs) pointed to the post build location.

There is no real way to reflect the dll's path at runtime, as far as I know....

So, when I entered the function with the dll copy, OF COURSE there are no global variables, because it is a FRESH COPY of the dll. That is expected behavior.

The memory debugger was correct, because somewhere the other dll was in memory holding the correct variable.

How could I prevent this in the future? It seemed VS was duped when it loaded a copy of the same dll.