# Could a managed thread affect globals in a C dll?

Tags: c#, c, multithreading, dll, global-variables

In reference to this question:
[Unable to see global variable in certain C file, value seems to reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18906522/unable-to-see-global-variable-in-certain-c-file-value-seems-to-reset)

The function that is called in a managed thread seems to lose its ability to see global variables on the unmanaged end. The variables are initialized using a non threaded call.

It is not a `ThreadPool` Thread, just:

```
Thread T = new Thread();
```

And the dll call is in the delegate.

**This is an anomaly on my PC** , and I'm wondering if there is some setting in VS that could influence this, or if threading can cause issues like this. I am not an expert on threading.

Tested in both VS 2010, and 2013.

Answer (score 0):

C# programs live in their own managed memory pool, so I doubt a managed thread could affect globals in a C dll unless that C code is specifically using memory within the C# programs - but I believe that would cause a page fault anyways.